# Table and chart for each employee on a different page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, grouping

I am trying to create a report in SSRS 2016 with a table of data and chart for each employee on a different page. I am able to group the table for each employee on a different page but the chart shows up on the last page for all the employees.

Is there a way to show the chart for each employee on a different page in SSRS (Visual Studio 2017)?